# Is it safe to use numbers in your web page file names?

Tags: html, numbers, filenames

Someone recently told me that using numbers in web page file names is not good practice. For example, say I was making a website about Samara Morgan and I had a file named `7days.html` - would it be bad to start the file name with a number? Is it riskier than having numbers put later in the file name (ie. `day7.html`)?

I'm just a tad confused on whether it's generally discouraged to use numbers in file names or not.

EDIT: After asking them to explain a bit more, this is what they said to me:

> .... the simplest way I can explain it is that certain programming
>   languages and operating systems might be confused by putting the
>   number as the first character. In other words, it has a higher
>   potential for error, so it's not recommended. That being said, it IS
>   acceptable to use a number AFTER the first character.  By the way, a
>   domain name (like 4chan.org) is a little different because it's not a
>   file.
>
> Here are some more tips/best practices (you'll see it as #3):
>
> https://ed.fnal.gov/lincon/tech_web_naming.shtml

Comment: take a look a the naming conventio for windows  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx  and unix https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/   seems that there is not   restriction to starting with digit

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should be bad. Most systems support those filenames and process them just as the same as filenames not starting with a digit. My guess is – and it is just a guess, nothing more – that either older systems might not support it completely, or that those filenames can interfere with the language constructs of some shell language.

Comment: @scaisEdge I updated the post to include some more information about why they thought it was bad practice. Thanks for the links - it makes me wonder why they said 'certain operating systems' might be confused by it.

Comment: i have posted a brief answer  -- for some suggestion .. hope is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go back to this someone and ask them for more information - are they saying there's a security problem? a usability problem because of something users might want to do with it? a Search Engine Optimisation trick you're missing that would make it easier for people to find?

I can't actually think of why numbers in URLs would matter for any of these, however. It seems most likely they were thinking of SEO, because that's a constant battle between search engines (who want users to get the results they want) and publishers (who want to get their brand higher up the results) and full of half-understood experiments and dodgy advice.

It's also worth noting that URLs don't exactly have "filenames" at all - they're just a string that the browser sends to the server, and the server may or may not map to a file on disk. Look at the URL of this page, for instance - it contains enough information for the server to look up the right question in a database, plus some human-readable text which is mostly for SEO.

Your server has filenames, of course, but I can't think of any reason why having numbers in those would be a problem, let alone why it would apply particularly to web pages.

---

**Edit based on additional information supplied:**

Two things I notice about the link you've added: one, it's twenty years old; two, it includes detailed reasoning for every single point, except point 3. I can't think of any "programming languages and operating systems" that would have a problem with a leading digit. It's actually quite common in some (non-web) contexts, as a way of forcing files to be listed or run in the desired order (e.g. `01-contents.txt`, `02-introduction.txt`, etc).

I can imagine problems if you began the filename with a `.`, `-`, or `_`, because sometimes there are entrenched conventions that those are hidden, or backups, etc. Either the advice made sense 20 years ago, or the author was being overly conservative to keep the rule simple.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my post to include some more information about why they thought it was bad practice. What do you think?

Comment: @JonathanMicaelPicazo Updated. I still can't think of a good reason to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise . Your question refers to whether it is permissible or appropriate to begin the name of a file with an o or more numeric characters .. and according to convenzini on die files used by (main operating system names) this type of naming is allowed and does not present any problem we use it to enterpretazione ..

windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

linux https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/

the situation slightly different for the programming languages ​​and the most common case is that of C / C ++ where the use of variables with completely numeric characters or compound nouns that begin with numeric characters can be confusing, and therefore this practice is by some not recommended.
(See this SO for C/C++ vars naming samples and problem  [Is it safe to use numbers in your web page file names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612777/is-it-safe-to-use-numbers-in-your-web-page-file-names?noredirect=1#comment72357161_42612777))

Therefore, in your case that refers to names of files .. the limitations that you have been inidicate are not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

No just keep it like that it doesn't effect anything